# Prevent powershell from changing title of command window

Tags: command-line, powershell

I've got a batch file that sets the title of the command window and then runs various commands. One of them is a powershell script which is launched something like:

```
powershell -file "scipt.ps1"
```

When this runs, the title bar of the command window gets changed to "PowerShell", is there a way of preventing it so that the title the batch file sets sticks?

Comment: Use `powershell .\%*` or `powershell .\scipt.ps1`

Answer (score 2):

you can prepend `start` to the command in the script that will open it in a separate powershell console window instead of running inside `cmd.exe`

or use that after the command

```
$host.ui.rawui.windowtitle='new title'
```

to change the title of powershell window

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

All you have to do is put `| title` after it then it wont show it.

Example:

```ps
powershell -file "script.ps1" | title
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).